# Property does not exist on type in Service

Tags: angular

I do have a service defined to get data from an API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'

import { bookingClass } from './list/list.component'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookingDataService {
  private apiBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getAllBookings(): Promise<bookingClass[]> {
    const url: string = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/bookings/listall`
    return this.http
      .get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response as bookingClass[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('Something has gone wrong', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

I use this service to populate a list:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookingDataService } from '../booking-data.service';

export class bookingClass {
  _id: string;
  timestamp: string;
  tags: string[];
  amount: number;
  type: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private bookingDataService: BookingDataService) { }

  public bookings: bookingClass[];

  private getBookings(): void {
    this.bookingDataService
      .getAllBookings()
      .then(foundBookings => this.bookings = foundBookings)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBookings();
  }

}
```

When running this with ng serve I'm getting an error

```
ERROR in src/app/list/list.component.ts(27,8): error TS2339: Property 'getAllBookings' does not exist on type 'BookingDataService'.
```

which I don't understand, as `getAllBookings` is public. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was completely unrelated to this: I used the wrong port number for the api call and I had a typo in the underlying express api.

Comment: I doubt that this could cause a `TypeScript` error, and definitely not the one you mentioned :) but glad you got it resolved. Did you follow my advice as well with putting the class in its own file?

Comment: I'll keep your advice in mind, thanks. This is an example project based on  https://www.manning.com/books/getting-mean-with-mongo-express-angular-and-node-second-edition chapter 8 which I'm currently going through. Probably the code will be refactored in the next chapters.

Answer (score 1):

You are having a circular dependency. `ListComponent` is importing `BookingDataService` and `BookingDataService` is in its turn importing `bookingClass` which is defined inside the list component file.

I can only imagine the error is coming from there. You should move your `bookingClass` to its own file and export/import it from there.

<sub>note: name classes in PascalCase :D and a class is not really necessary here. In my opioning is better to use an `Interface`, this way your compiled code does not get bloated</sub>